# vb allow user to select sql database file and change connection string(Dataset)

Tags: vb.net

i desperately need help on this as i checked online for many weeks. Upon login to my program, next form is to allow user to open window explorer and select the database(mdf) file, and change the connection string in my program so that the rest of the program can work. i had a dataset named CheckGoods and the current connection string is CheckGoodsConnectionString. Any kind help and advice would be very much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: i am quite new to vb and based on my search online, i tried bits and pieces from different websites, trying to make it work but unsuccessful.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using Windows Forms, you could present the user with a dialog box allowing the user to change the directory and pick a file with extension such as accdb (for MS-Access 2007 for example). After the user selects a file you can use that file name to form the connection string. For example:

```
Dim openFileDialog1 As New OpenFileDialog()
openFileDialog1.Title = "Select Database File"
openFileDialog1.Filter = "MS-Access Files|*.accdb"
openFileDialog1.FileName = ""
openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "C:\Temp"  'Suggested path for where the file could exist
openFileDialog1.ShowDialog()

If openFileDialog1.FileName = "" Then
    Return                                'Decide what to do when no file is selected
End If

Dim dbNameWithPath As String = openFileDialog1.FileName 'openFileDialog1.FileName is where the selected file is stored
Dim connStr As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ace.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & dbNameWithPath
```

In case you are using SQL Server Express (2012 for example), the connection string would look like:

```
"Server=.\SQLExpress;AttachDbFilename=C:\MyFolder\MyDataFile.mdf;Database=dbname;Trusted_Connection=Yes;"
```

In the above string you could replace the string value for AttachDbFileName and dbname based on user choice. However, this process is not without problems!

Comment: thank u so much. As i am using sql, may i know if i need to change the syntax for connStr "provider=Microsoft.ace.. ..". also, how will this change the existing connectionstring with my current dataset CheckGoods which is already in few other forms. sorry not sure if i am clear but hope you can advice further.

Comment: just to share more, i have few other forms that uses the dataset dsCheckGoods and the different datatableadaptors are used in different forms. with your advice, i am able to select the database file, but the problem is how do i update the current connection string in the entire program to this user selected connection? please help. Thanks.

Comment: If you are using SQL Server, then you need a different connection string. If you are using SQL Server Express, you may be able to do what you want. As per where you should put the code, you could have the code that sets the database string immediately after your InitializeComponent() code the store the connection string in a public variable or a module. Show me your current connection string so that I could see if it fits with this method or not. It is important to check whether you are using SQL Server Express or SQL Server (or other type).

Comment: thanks for your prompt reply and advice. i am using sql express.i think the current connectionstring in stored in app.config. <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
    </configSections>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="nCheck.My.MySettings.CheckNumberConnectionString"
            connectionString="Data Source=SHAWNTAN-HM\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=F:\Programming\ASP\nCheck\CheckNumber.mdf;Integrated Security=True"
            providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>

Comment: i am now able to select the database and but i am not sure how to change the connection string with this or where to change it. kindly advise further. thanks in advance.

Comment: If this is an application you wish to give to users, the string could be set up in the app.config but there is a different process for that. Simplest approach is to change the values in the app.config via text editor or having a menu function (or similar) that would use the above example then write the settings to app.config file. See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a65txexh%28v=vs.110%29.aspx. If this is a practice app, change the settings manually, the parameters are rather clear.